# Is there a way to cache RenderFragment output?

Tags: c#, caching, blazor-webassembly

Is it possible to cache the output of a RenderFragment in Blazor WebAssembly?
Specifically, this is to retain components shown intermittently without rendering them to the browser. With "rendering to the browser" here I mean outputting HTML to the browser.
I am trying to get this to work to improve performance in a library I am writing where two-dimensional data is shown in the browser. The resulting grid is virtualized to prevent having tens of thousands of elements in the DOM since having that many elements results in a degraded experience.
When virtualizing, elements outside the view are not rendered only to be rendered when they shift into view.

The caching mechanism should preserve the HTML output of Razor Components such that the components can be removed from and added to the DOM without having to be reinitialized and rerendered.
Currently, I have not found a way to achieve this.

A basic set-up to reproduce what I have tried so far is as follows:
create a Blazor WebAssembly project using the default template without hosting.
Add a Razor Component with the name ConsoleWriter.razor to Shared and set the contents as follows:

```
<h3>ConsoleWriter @Name</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        Console.WriteLine($"ConsoleWriter {this.Name} initialized");
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) {
        if(firstRender) {
            Console.WriteLine($"ConsoleWriter {this.Name} rendered");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine($"ConsoleWriter {this.Name} re-rendered");
        }
    }

    // Trying to stop rerendering with ShouldRender.
    // Does not stop the rendering in scenario's where the component has just been initialized.
    protected override bool ShouldRender() => false;
}
```

Replace the contents of Index.razor with the following code:

```
@page "/"

<p>Components are showing: @showComponents</p>
<button @onclick="() => this.showComponents=!this.showComponents">Toggle</button>

@* Here the components are in the DOM but can be hidden from view, still bogging down the DOM if there are too many. *@
<div style="@(this.showComponents ? null : "display:none;")">
    <ConsoleWriter Name="OnlyHidden" /> @* Does not intialize or rerender when showComponents is toggled *@
</div>

@* Here the components are not in the DOM at all when hidden, which is the intended scenario but this initializes the components every time they are shown. *@
@if(this.showComponents) {
    <ConsoleWriter Name="Default" /> @* Intializes and rerenders when showComponents is toggled *@
    @consoleWriter @* Intializes and rerenders when showComponents is toggled *@
    <ConsoleWriter @key="consoleWriterKey" Name="WithKey" /> @* Intializes and rerenders when showComponents is toggled *@
}

@code {
    private bool showComponents = false;
    private object consoleWriterKey = new object();

    private RenderFragment consoleWriter { get; } = builder => {
        builder.OpenComponent<ConsoleWriter>(0);
        builder.AddAttribute(1, nameof(ConsoleWriter.Name), "RenderFragment");
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

When running the project and checking the browser console, you can see which components report being reinitialized or rerendered.
The components can be toggled by clicking the button.
Unfortunately, all of those being removed from and added to the DOM report back whenever being toggled to be shown despite their content never changing.

Does anyone have another idea how to approach this?

Comment: Why are you spending time on this? Have you identified a performance issue? If so, why not ask about ways to address that specific issue. As it stands this question is not specific or clear enough.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Yes, I'm having trouble because I need to virtualize a 2D square grid with 50.000+ cells. 
Pushing that many elements to the DOM is a recipe for a laggy experience, but virtualizing them causes everything within the viewport to be re-rendered when the boundaries of the virtual area are reached. With the amount of cells within the viewport, this recalculation too gets too expensive.
So I'm left with trying to find a way to keep the already rendered parts that are still within view rendered.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Unfortunately for me, yes. I figured that out after trying to use that to solve this.
I just put that in the question to prevent people who also didn't know from proposing the use of RenderFragment.

Comment: You said "virtualizing them causes everything within the viewport to be re-rendered when the boundaries of the virtual area are reached" That seems like the problem you should solve.